# Asp.net Web Forms (NOT MVC) azure active directory authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth-2.0, webforms, azure-active-directory

I am supposed to develop azure AD authentication for a web application. The user will enter his/her email address and password, the email and password should be validated with Azure Active Directory. If the user credentials are valid then authenticate the user and redirect to some page.

Your help much appreciated as I have been stuck with this point since two days with no progress.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the `MSAL` (Microsoft Authentication Library) library and the documentation is pretty good. You can read more about how to do this using `MSAL` here: [Azure AD Authentication Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-overview?tabs=aspnetcore) and [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

Comment: Thanks saw the example but I am looking for an example that covers asp.net web forms without MVC

Comment: Shouldn't matter, the authentication is going to work the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As   [Ryan Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830196/ryan-wilson) said the authentication is going to work the same for all asp.net applications, posting his suggestion to help other  community members.

Here is an example i tried with `ASP.Net core webapp`  and you can follow the same  steps for your environment as well:
Created tenant in Azure active directory and switch to my created tenant

[image]

From tenant i created App registration  with providing localhost.

[image]

[image]

After Register Go to > Overview > Copy all the credentials like client ID, tenant id, Redirect URL and keep a note for further use as below:

[image]

Clicked on authentication option from manage then checked ID TOKEN . And to use single tenant mark as yes and save it.

[image]

For an example from  visual studio i have created ASP.Net core web app and installed the following `Nuget package` to the project
**Microsoft.AspNetCore.authentication.AzureAD** **& Microsoft.Identity.Web** in the Nuget package installer from root of your project:

[image]

In  `statup.cs` file and update under the configuration services as below

```
      public  void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection(****"AzureAd"****));
  
         services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
    }
```

and update the authentication as below:

**app.UseAuthentication();**
app.UseAuthorization();

[image]

And in  **appsetting.json** file and updated the below details which noted from above overview of App registration.

```
{
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "demotest.onmicrosoft.com",
"ClientId": "*****",
"TenantId": " ****** " ,
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

[image]

From `homecontroler.cs` file added a attribute called **[Authorize]**

[image]

And run the application which will redirect MSAL page as below :

[image]

For more information please refer this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-azure-ad-authentication-using-net-5-0-web-api/)  & [MS DOC devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/)

Comment: The question was about **ASP.NET Web Forms** not ASP.NET MVC nor ASP.NET Core. How can **Startup.cs** and **ConfigureServices** be used in ASP.NET Web Forms?